# Printing booklet with Glossy Cover?

Tags: print-design, booklet

I need to print a booklet but want the cover and back cover to be glossy paper, the other pages inside the booklet i want to be regular paper. I use fiery command workstation for printing. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is that 'printing' as in pressing Ctrl+P and see the sheets come from your desktop printer; or sending a .pdf to a company that produces the things for you?

Comment: What's your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

Load different paper.

If you are imposing a large sheet, you can split it into two jobs and do the covers on a smaller press or smaller sheets.

If you need matte on the inside covers, laminate two sheets or use a laminated paper stock.

If you cannot do the above, consider aqueous/varnish/UV for the outside covers only.